# Postgres 9.0 File System level backup on Debian Jessie

Tags: postgresql, debian, postgresql-9.0

I'm on Debian 8.2.0 and trying to run a postgres server from a folder I received. Version is 9.0.18. Here is the command I issue:

```
./postgres -D /home/swapps/project/PostgreSQL/9.0/data/
```

but the cursor keeps blinking in the terminal. I'm not sure what is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Psst: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/server-start.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it's started, and `log_min_messages` is set to a high enough value that you don't see any output.

Using another terminal session connect to the server on the port it's running on. If you don't know that check the `port` value in the `postgresql.conf` inside the data directory.

Generally you should use `pg_ctl -D blah -w start` rather than `postgres` directly. See [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/server-start.html).

Or, for long term use, set it up to run on startup via an init script.